# DCEF3: How to get a screenshot

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, chromium-embedded, tchromium

How to get screenshot of browser in DCEF3?

I create browser like this without VCL. The `TakePicture` method will only work if

- No debugger is used
- If ShowWindow is used

  ```
  var
    info: TCefWindowInfo;
    Settings: TCefBrowserSettings;
  begin
    FillChar(info, SizeOf(info), 0);
    info.width := width;
    info.height := height;
    FillChar(Settings, SizeOf(TCefBrowserSettings), 0);
    Settings.Size := SizeOf(TCefBrowserSettings);
    GetSettings(Settings);
    CefBrowserHostCreateBrowser(@info, FHandler, FDefaultUrl, @settings, nil);
  end;

  procedure TakePicture(const Browser: ICefBrowser; Height, Width: Integer);
  var
    DC: HDC;
    Bmp : TBitmap;
    Handle : HWND;
    Rect : trect;
    BarHeight : integer;
    BarLeft : integer;
  begin
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Handle := Browser.Host.WindowHandle;
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE); // will work only if this is used otherwise black image!
    BarLeft := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME);
    BarHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME);
    GetWindowRect(Handle, Rect);
    DC := GetDC(Handle);
    Bmp.Width := Rect.Right - Rect.Left;
    Bmp.Height := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top);
    BitBlt(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, DC, -BarLeft, -BarHeight, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
    Bmp.SaveToFile('c:\test.bmp');
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
  ```

Comment: Doesn't this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661250/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-active-window-in-delphi

Comment: Please update your question with the actual snapshot code you are using that currently fails.

Comment: Can't you just use the `CefGetBitmap` function ?

Comment: @TLama i don't think DCEF3 supports it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is the DCEF1 which has [`this procedure`](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/src/cefvcl.pas#481)...

Comment: @TLama Could it work with DCEF3 ?

Comment: I don't think so. At least, there is no `ICefBrowser::GetImage` method in CEF3.

Comment: @TLama Could it be done with this? http://pastebin.com/dbj3MYdZ

Comment: In that code I can't see anything attempting to render the content to a bitmap.

Comment: Yes but it is rendering to a window.

Comment: @TLama I get black image when i try to save as image. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically off-screen rendering. In the demos folder of DCEF3 you'll find a project 'offscreen'. The code you're looking for is in the `OnPaint` event of `TChromiumOSR`. It renders to a [TBitmap32](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Units/GR32/Classes/TBitmap32/_Body.htm), but any bitmap could be made to work. Notice that it has been optimized to only paint the so-called "dirty" areas (those that have changed since last painting), but if you're making a screenshot, that's not what you want. In my check-out of the repository there's a line commented out showing the naive case of just painting everything:

```
SomeBitmap.SetSize(width, height);
Move(buffer^, SomeBitmap32.Bits^, width * height * 4);
```

It's my best guess that the magic number `4` represents 4 bytes (32-bits).

I warmly recommend using Graphics32 but it you have to use a regular TBitmap, I'll leave it up to you to work out how to turn the array of bits into pixels. Be warmed it will probably be a lot slower.

Comment: Not much help this answer. Need concrete example.

Comment: @user3655788 My answer basically tells you where to find the example.

Comment: I get a black image. I doubt i need to use offscreen rendering to get a simple screenshot. Thats for firemonkey.

Comment: @user3655788 Try that demo; it works. There's not really any VCL involved there until the `TBitmap32` is rendered by the `TPaintBox32`. Have a good look at it and translate it to your own code but it basically comes down to the above. A "simple screenshot" still involves rendering the website. If you don't have it rendered to the form already (in which case you could use the link @JanDoggen provided), you'll need to render off-screen.

Comment: @user3655788 The only problem you might run into with that demo is that you need to change `event.type_` into `event.kind` (error when compiling).

Comment: Problem is this `OnPaint` is not even called.